# MouseArea does not function inside a disabled Slider

Tags: qt, qml

I have the code below, which contains a **MouseArea** inside a **Slider**. When the **Slider** is `enabled: false`, the **MouseArea** no longer works.
Do you have a solution?

```js
RowLayout {
    id: rowLayoutSlider
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 20

    Text {
        id: sliderValueLabel
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width * 0.5
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }

    Slider {
        id: sliderElement
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width * 0.5
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
        stepSize: 0.001
        from: 1
        to: 500
        value: 100
        enabled: valide // variable
        
        MouseArea {
            id: conditionalMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log("click here");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put the **MouseArea** outside, but it gives me the error:

> MouseArea: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.

This error occurs because the **MouseArea** is inside the **RowLayout**.

Comment: By disabling an item, its children will also be disabled. Additionally, for the anchor problem, you cannot set anchors to children of a *Grid/Row/ColumnLayout*. Also you can try using PointHandler or other types of event handlers.

Comment: Parent the Slider inside an Item and put the MouseArea as a sibling to the Item. The MouseArea can function independently of the Slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack the slider and the mouse area in an parent `Item`. This is what Stephen Quan suggested as well.

```
RowLayout {
    id: rowLayoutSlider
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 20

    Text {
        id: sliderValueLabel
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }

    // use an parent item to stack the slider and the mouse area
    Item {
        id: parentItem

        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight

        Slider {
            id: sliderElement

            anchors.fill: parentItem

            stepSize: 0.001
            from: 1
            to: 500
            value: 100

            enabled: false // variable
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: conditionalMouseArea

            anchors.fill: parentItem

            // only enable the mouse area if the slider is disabled
            enabled: !sliderElement.enabled

            onClicked: (mouse) => {
                           console.log("click here");
                       }
        }
    }


}
```